# Algorithm to Create All "Spot it!" Cards

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, card-games

"Spot it!" is a fun card game, played with 55 cards, each having eight symbols. There are more than 50 symbols in all. There is always one, and only one, matching symbol between any two cards, and this is the feature on which all the games playable with these cards are based. Some mathematical aspects of the game are discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/what-is-the-math-behind-the-game-spot-it) before.

[image]

Here's my question: How are these cards designed?! Put in a more mathematical way, **is there an algorithm (not a brute-froce on!) to find all subsets of size $k$ of a set of size $n$, so that each two subsets have exactly one element in common?**

Thanks.

**Upadte:** It seems that my question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240113/what-are-the-mathematical-computational-principles-behind-this-game/6240247#6240247).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the math behind the game Spot It?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/what-is-the-math-behind-the-game-spot-it); although the question is not identical, I think the given answers address the current question as well. See also [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240113/what-are-the-mathematical-computational-principles-behind-this-game)

Comment: Well, I looked at the other post on Stackexchange and it doesn't address my problem. BUT, you're right! That post on Stackoverflow is likely to be what I wanted.

Comment: I've converted into a [cards generator](https://funcards.github.io/match-it)