# Sets of $N$ symbols with $1$ repetition

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of $X$ symbols which I have to put in cards of $N$ (where $X > N$) slots such that every card must have exactly $1$ symbol in common with each other. What I want to know is, how many cards can I form? I don't even know how to mathematically formulate this, how do I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean every set of two cards should have exactly one symbol in common?

Comment: I meant that every card must have a common symbol with every other card. Like, suppose we have a card with symbols "A B C" all other cards must have one of those symbols

Comment: Well, you need to say more than that.  If my symbols were, as you say, $A,B,C$ then I could  have infinitely many cards each just using the symbol $A$.  That satisfies your stated requirements, but I seriously doubt you would allow that configuration.

Comment: I would assume the cards have to be distinct.

Comment: "Every card must have **exactly** 1 symbol in common..."  It sounds like you are referring to the game "Spot It."  See the following: [What is the math behind the game Spot It?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/what-is-the-math-behind-the-game-spot-it?rq=1), [What are the mathematical computational principles behind this game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240113/what-are-the-mathematical-computational-principles-behind-this-game/), [Algorithm to Create all Spot It cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500336/algorithm-to-create-all-spot-it-cards).

Comment: @JMoravitz exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030747/177399) for discussion of how your problem relates to Steiner systems.