# Proof on "No rectangles" on a grid

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving a [problem](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=71) of the UVA judge called "No rectangles".  The problem is about picking points from an $n\times n$ grid such that $k$ points are chosen from each row and column but no $4$ of the points form a rectangle with sides parallel to the grid. They claim the following in the statement of the problem

> It can easily be shown that for any given value of $k$, $k^2 − k + 1$ is a
>   lower bound on the value of $n$, and it can be shown further that $n$ need
>   never be larger than this.

Proving this statement is not necessary to solve the problem. However, I've been thinking on how to prove it and I do not know how I could do it. Any hints/clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proof of the lower bound.  Let us consider the chosen points in each row as a subset of $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$, so we are selecting $n$ subsets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ of $S$, each of size $k$, so that each element of $S$ is in $k$ of the $A_i$'s.  Avoiding rectangles means that $|A_i\cap A_j|\leq 1$ if $i\neq j$.

Now consider the $k$ different $A_i$ such that $1\in A_i$.  All of the elements of these sets must be distinct except for $1$, so each one has $k-1$ elements that are not in any of the others.  This gives $k(k-1)+1=k^2-k+1$ different elements of $S$ (the $k-1$ unique elements of the $k$ sets, plus the element $1$).  Thus $n\geq k^2-k+1$.

---

The claim that $n=k^2-k+1$ is possible in general is incorrect, however.  Indeed, observe that when $n=k^2-k+1$, the argument above shows that for every $j\in S\setminus\{1\}$, there is exactly one $A_i$ which contains both $1$ and $j$.  Similarly, every two-element subset of $S$ is contained in exactly one $A_i$.  That is, in terms of the original grid formulation, for every pair of columns there is exactly one row with a point in both columns.  Dually, for every pair of rows there must be exactly one column with a point in both rows.  This means that such a configuration is exactly the incidence relation of a [finite projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes), with the rows representing points and the columns representing lines.  (Thanks to antkam for suggesting this connection in a comment!)

Given a finite projective plane with $n=k^2-k+1$ points, the number $k-1$ is known as the *order* of the projective plane.  Not every number can be the order of a projective plane; for instance, it is known that there is no projective plane of order $6$, so the statement you quoted is wrong for $k=7$.  It is known that projective planes exist for any prime power order and it is conjectured (but not known!) that these are the only possible orders.

Here is how you can construct an example when $k-1$ is a prime power.  The key fact we use is that then there exists a field $F$ with $k-1$ elements.  Let us then think of our $(k^2-k+1)$-element set $S$ as $$\{0\}\cup((F\cup\{\infty\})\times F).$$  Our first $k$ sets $A_1,\dots,A_k$ are just $\{0\}\cup\{x\}\times F$ for each $x\in F\cup\{\infty\}$.  The remaining sets will then all be subsets of $(F\cup\{\infty\})\times F$ which contain one element from each $\{x\}\times F$, so they are just (graphs of) functions $F\cup\{\infty\}\to F$.  So, we need to pick $n-k=k^2-2k+1=(k-1)^2$ functions $F\cup\{\infty\}\to F$ such that every possible ordered pair is in exactly $k-1$ of the functions and no two functions have more than one point in common.  To do this, for each $a,b\in F$ define $f_{a,b}(x)=ax+b$ for $x\in F$ and $f_{a,b}(\infty)=a$.  These functions $f_{a,b}$ have the desired properties because $F$ is a field (so that any two points of $F^2$ with different first coordinates can be interpolated by a unique linear function; similarly given any point in $F^2$ and a choice of slope there is a unique linear function through that line with that slope).

(This construction is known as the projective plane over $F$ and can be described in many other ways.  One particularly elegant way is to say that the rows of the grid correspond to 1-dimensional subspaces of the vector space $F^3$, the columns correspond to 2-dimensional subspaces of $F^3$, and you draw a point whenever the 1-dimensional subspace corresponding to a row is contained in the 2-dimensional subspace corresponding to a column.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the 2nd half of your answer (the existence part) reconstructed  [Finite Projective Planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes).  These exist whenever (in the current context) $k-1$ is prime or a prime power.  But the curious thing is that if $k-1$ is not a prime (power), then no known FPPs exist (and in partcular for $k-1=6$ it is known FPPs cannot exist).  And yet, the OP question boldly states existence of $n=k^2-k+1$ for any $k$...  Either we're missing something (i.e. using FPP is not necessary), or the OP claim is wrong.

Comment: @antkam: I'm not very familiar with the topic but that sounds correct to me.  If I'm not mistaken, then a solution to the problem as stated with $n=k^2-k+1$ is exactly the same thing as an incidence relation for the points and lines of a projective plane of order $k-1$.

Comment: I also mainly just know what wikipedia said. :) However, in a FPP, every two lines intersect at one point.  There is no equivalent requirement in the OP stmt, which would have been: every two rows have one column where both intersections are picked.  Instead the OP requirement is: every two rows have _zero or one_ column where both intersections are picked.  This is an additional degree of freedom.  However, I somehow suspect, at the min value of $n= k^2-k+1$, that the two requirements might be equivalent... in which case the OP claim is false for $k-1=6$ and open for non-prime-powers.

Comment: @antkam Yes, when $n=k^2-k+1$ the requirements are equivalent.  I was just in the process of updating my answer to talk about that. :)

Comment: BTW, if you didn't know FPPs before, then _CONGRATULATIONS_ for re-inventing them!  :D I had such a re-invention moment a few years ago, and it was very exciting for me.  (Well I only solved it for the case of order $7$, and didn't realize it has a geometric interpretation, but still!) I re-invented it when I met the card game Spot It which uses an FPP.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/what-is-the-math-behind-the-game-spot-it) for more fun details.

Comment: I knew of them before and was vaguely aware of some of the general facts but did not make the connection when thinking about this problem.